# Insert/Update Record on other Object

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

Requirement :- Need to Insert records in to Custom object (Merged_Account__c) and Update when Account with same id already present in Merged_Account__C.

Merged_Account__C Object having custom fields(Name,**Servive_Accoun_Id**,Servive_Account_number).
I am storing the **Account id in Servive_Account_Id** in Custom Object.

I Have written the logic ,its working as expected but I am not sure about the best Practices and bulkification of code.Please suggest 
Here Is My code

```
trigger OnOtherCustomObject on Account (After insert,after Update) {
Map<id,account>AccountMap=new Map<Id,account>();
List<Merged_Account__c> MgInsert=new List<Merged_Account__c>();
if(trigger.isInsert){
    For(Account Ac:Trigger.new){
        MgInsert.add(new Merged_Account__c(
            Name=ac.Name,
            Servive_Account_ID__c=ac.id,
            Servive_Account_Number__c=ac.accountnumber,
            Servive_Account_Site__c=ac.site)); 
    }
    if(MgInsert.size()>0){
        Insert MgInsert;
    }
}

If(trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
        AccountMap.put(acc.id,acc);
    }    
}
List<Merged_Account__c>MapCustomObject=new List<Merged_Account__c>([select Servive_Account_ID__c from Merged_Account__c where Servive_Account_ID__c in:AccountMap.keySet()]);
List<Merged_Account__c> MgUpdate=new List<Merged_Account__c>();
for(Merged_Account__c ms:MapCustomObject){
    Account acc=AccountMap.get(ms.Servive_Account_ID__c);
    ms.Servive_Account_ID__c=acc.id;
    ms.Servive_Account_Number__c=acc.AccountNumber;
    ms.Servive_Account_Site__c=acc.Site;
    MgUpdate.add(ms);
}
if(MgUpdate.size()>0){
    Update MgUpdate;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me as far as bulkification is concerned in that there are no queries or DML inside the loops.

As `Account` is an object shared across all apps in an org, your trigger will add a cost - a query and an update - to all `Account` changes even if they are unrelated to your purpose. That cost is minor in terms of performance but might take some future logic over a governor limit and then it will be a major cost. So I suggest only doing the query and update when either `AccountNumber` or `Site` change by comparing the `Trigger.new` values with the `Trigger.oldMap` values:

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        Account old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        if (a.AccountNumber != old.AccountNumber || a.Site != old.Site) {
            accountIds.add(a.Id);
        }
    }
    if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
        Merged_Account__c[] mas = [
                select Id
                from Merged_Account__c
                where Servive_Account_ID__c in :accountIds
                ];
        for (Merged_Account__c ma : mas) {
            Account a = Trigger.newMap.get(ma.Servive_Account_ID__c);
            ma.Servive_Account_Number__c = a.AccountNumber;
            ma.Servive_Account_Site__c = a.Site;
        }
        update mas;
    }    
}
```